# Do Shell Script with Admin Privileges Custom Icon

Tags: macos, applescript

I am using AppleScript to run a shell script as admin.

```
do shell script custom_command with prompt custom_prompt with administrator privileges
```

which gives me this prompt that is fine, but I would like to be able to change the icon to something other than a terminal icon. Any help would be appreciated.

[image: prompt]

Comment: The badge icon comes from whatever application is using the command.

Comment: @red_menace I am using `osascript -e` is there no way to change it?

Comment: No, the shell is what is ultimately running the script, so that is the icon the system uses.  You can call a helper app that does the shell script, but that seems like a bit of a runaround.

Comment: @red_menace I would actually be interested in this. How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The badge on the authentication dialog comes from the application that is using the command.

To get a custom badge for the icon you can use a helper AppleScript application to run your script, but if the `osascript` is all you are doing, you can just do everything by using the app (otherwise all you are doing is using an `osascript` to run an AppleScript that runs an `osascript`).  To create an application for the `osascript`, edit your script in the **Script Editor**, for example:

```
do shell script "echo 'this is a test' >> ~/Desktop/Testing.txt" with administrator privileges
```

then save it as an application (leave the options unchecked).  Rename a copy of the icon file you want to use to **applet.icns**, open the app bundle, and replace the existing icon file in **/Contents/Resources/**.  You can then run the application from the **Terminal** by using `open /path/to/your/app`

The main icon will still be the padlock, but the badge will now be your application icon.

To pass arguments to an *application* is a little different than an *osascript*, but a little bit of AppleScriptObjC takes care of that:

```
use framework "Foundation"
use scripting additions

# the first argument item is the applet/droplet executable path, so we'll just skip that
set args to rest of (arguments of current application's NSProcessInfo's processInfo() as list)

if args is not {} then
  do shell script "echo " & first item of args & " >> ~/Desktop/Testing.txt" with administrator privileges
end if
```

You can run *that* by using `open /path/to/your/app --args “this is a test”`